# MongoDb Insert many not working with ordered false option in transaction

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am creating a collection blog with the following unique index:

```
{
    "title" : 1,
    "author" : 1
}
unique:true
```

This collection consists the following document

```
 {
"title":"Java",
"author":"ABC",
code:123
}
```

Now I want to insert the following document into it

```
[{
    "title":"JAVA",
    "author":"ABC",
    code:234
    }]
```

I am using insertMany query to add this to the collection. but the collection has a unique index. so when I try to insert the above document in the collection it will give an error like the title is not unique. but I want check other field error also here so I am using insertMany query with ordered option like:

```
db.insertMany("blog",[{
    "title":"JAVA",
    "author":"ABC",
    code:234
    }]
, {ordered: false})
```

the above query error gives me all two field names. but when I am trying to use this with Mongodb transaction it will gives only one field error I am using Transaction like:

```
let session = await db.startSession({});
db.insertMany("blog",[{
    "title":"JAVA",
    "author":"ABC",
    code:234
    }]
, {ordered: false, session})
```

SO how I get all fields name in result whose no unique using insertMany, ordered, and session? Kindly help me here

Comment: kindly help me here

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs...

> Inside a transaction, the first error in a bulk write causes the entire bulk write to fail and aborts the transaction, even if the bulk write is unordered.

[Mongodb Docs - BulkWrite](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#error-handling-inside-transactions)

Comment: OP is not using `bulkWrite` though—the code has `insertMany`.